# What is Button element in HTML

Tags: html, web

This is my sample code
   Thanks a lot for looking at my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>calculator</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center><h2>calculator</h2></center>
<table border="5px" width="400px" cellspacing="30px" cellpadding="20px" align="center">
<tr>
<td style="border:0;font-style:red"><center><h3>CASIO</h3></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="border:0px">
<input type="text" id="txtans" style="width:250px;height:25px;font-size:20px" dir="rtl">
</td>
<td style="background-color:rgb(212, 212, 12)">clear</td>
<td style="background-color:red">on/of</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:gray">mc</td>
<td style="background-color:gray">mr</td>
<td style="background-color:gray">m-</td>
<td style="background-color:gray">m+</td>
<td style="background-color:gray">HMS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>*</td>
<td style="background-color:cyan">ac</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td rowspan="2">+</td>
<td>/</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>+/-</td>
<td>.</td>
<td>=</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me add "button" functionality in this code so that when I run this program in my browser I can click the number buttons and work on calculation!

Comment: The element is button. Then you need some JavaScript to get your goal

Comment: What your looking for is JavaScript. If you don’t already know it look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach to try to explain to you :

https://jsfiddle.net/wqo6Lxks/

```
<td onclick="document.getElementById('txtans').value += 3">3</td>
<td onclick="eval(document.getElementById('txtans').value)">=</td>
```

Each td needs an action (onclick) to insert his content into txtans, and = eval() calculate this string.